# Ionic serve and Ionic run android livereload give timeout

Tags: timeout, ionic-framework, gulp, livereload, serve

recently I was unable to debug in serve mode or livereload... Does anyone have some suggestion because I'm a bit lost right now..

Ionic 1.2.1
Ionic CLI 1.7.9
Cordova 5.4.1

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l4MJA.png)

Comment: you're on Windows and it seems like firewall blocks

Comment: thanks for the hint, I deactivated it but then I got a net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED (http://XXX.XXX.X.XXX:8100/) error... Is there something in Ionic to allow all connections?